# Active spaces with xstring's StrSubstitute

Tags: spacing, catcodes, xstring

I have some text that I would like to preprocess using `xstring`'s `\StrSubstitute` method (basically replacing certain keywords by simple commands such as `foobar` by `\emph{foobar}`). There are two side conditions which make this tough (at least I haven't been able to figure out how to do this). On the one hand, I need to run `\StrSubstitute` in `noexpandarg` mode, on the other I would like to use active spaces in order to print out the input obeying spaces. I know there are environments such as `listings` or `verbatim` but these won't work for what I have in mind: in the very end the thus preprocessed string should go into an (`amsmath`) `align` environment.

So here is what I have

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\begingroup
\catcode`\@=\active
\lccode`\@=`\ % At-sign is a space
\lowercase{%
  \endgroup
  \newenvironment{withspaces}{%
    \catcode`\ =\active % Space active
    \let@=~%
   }{ 
}}

\begin{document}

\def\foo{foo}
\begin{withspaces}
There is space before        \foo foo
\end{withspaces}

\begin{withspaces}
\StrSubstitute{There is space before        \foo foo}{foo}{bar}
\end{withspaces}

\noexpandarg % in order to first run the string substitution and only then expand \foo
\StrSubstitute{There is space before        \foo foo}{foo}{bar}

% The following breaks down to the noexpandarg flag
\begin{withspaces}
%\StrSubstitute{There is space before        \foo foo}{foo}{bar}
\end{withspaces}


\end{document}
```

The `withspaces` environment (adapted from Joseph's answer [Environment that obeys spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53723/environment-that-obeys-spaces)) seems to work fine both in text mode and in math mode. The first use of `\StrSubstitute`works as it is in `fullyexpandmode`. The result then, however, is that first `\foo` is expanded and then replaced by `\StrSubstitute` which is why I think I need to use `noexpandarg`: `\StrSubstitute` should do the substitution without expanding `\foo`.

This also works fine in isolation. That is,

```
\noexpandarg % in order to first run the string substitution and only then expand \foo
\StrSubstitute{There is space before        \foo foo}{foo}{bar}
```

yields the desired result but without active spaces. Once I try to combine the two (uncommenting out the last `\StrSubstitute` in the MWE) I am stuck at

```
Argument of \@xs@behindspace has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.33 \end
         {withspaces}
```

And here is where I am lost.

Comment: Why not adding `\noexpandarg` to the definition of `withspaces`?

Comment: @egreg in the example I wanted to emphasize that it works without `\noexpandarg` (i.e. full expansion mode) but not with it. If I add it to the `withspaces` environment then already the first `StrSubstitute` fails.

Comment: Would a solution without `xstring` be acceptable?

Comment: Yes. What I need is the capability of parsing the input and replace keywords by simple macros, i.e., replace foobar by `\highlight{foobar}`. Currently I am implementing this with a sequence of StrSubstitutes but anything that provides the functionality (i.e. str replacement without expansion + spacing) is fine.

Comment: To be more exact on what I am trying to do. I'd like to add the capability of automatic indentation for pseudocode generated with the cryptocode package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cryptocode). Cryptocode is a package I've developed over the last weeks to help typeset cryptographyic papers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look at an implementation using `l3regex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}
% \usepackage{l3tl-analysis} % uncomment for debugging

\newenvironment{withspaces}
 {\obeyspaces\begingroup\lccode`~=` \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}~}
 {}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_arno_strsub_input_tl
\tl_new:N \l_arno_strsub_search_tl
\tl_new:N \l_arno_strsub_replace_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\strsub}{mmm}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_arno_strsub_input_tl { #1 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_arno_strsub_search_tl { #2 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_arno_strsub_replace_tl { #3 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { \u{l_arno_strsub_search_tl} }
   { \u{l_arno_strsub_replace_tl} }
   \l_arno_strsub_input_tl
  %\tl_show_analysis:N  \l_arno_strsub_input_tl % uncomment for debugging
  \tl_use:N \l_arno_strsub_input_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\foo{foo}
\begin{withspaces}
There is space before        \foo foo
\end{withspaces}

\begin{withspaces}
\strsub{There is space before        \foo foo}{foo}{bar}
\end{withspaces}

\strsub{There is space before        \foo foo}{foo}{bar}

\begin{withspaces}
\strsub{Some  spaces  \foo foo}{foo}{\textbf{foo}}
\end{withspaces}

\end{document}
```

The search and replacement strings are stored into token lists, so they can be used “as is” for the regex business.

As you see in the last example, only the explicit appearance of `foo` has been replaced.

If you uncomment the lines marked “for debugging” you'll see in the terminal a representation of the strings after the regex replacement.

(For releases before TeX Live 2017, you will need `\usepackage{l3tl-analysis}` and `\usepackage{l3regex}` in addition to `\usepackage{xparse}` for this to work.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can define `\dospaces` as a prefix for `\StrSubstitute` macro:

```
\def\dospaces\StrSubstitute{\bgroup\catcode`\ =13 \let\protect=\noexpand \dospacesA}
\def\dospacesA#1{\xdef\tmp{#1}\egroup \expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tmp}}

%% usage:

\dospaces\StrSubstitute{There is space before        \foo foo}{foo}{bar}
```

Comment: That is an interesting construct (which I not fully understand). However, it seems that now first `\foo` is expanded and then the substitution occurs. That is the result is `There is space before    [space] bar bar` instead of `There is space before [space] foo bar`. My guess would be that the `\xdef` does a full expansion. If I put a `\noexpand\foo` then the result is correct. Can this expansion be somehow prohibited automatically?

Comment: @ArnoMittelbach I've added `\let\protect=\noexpand` into my code. Now, you can use `\DeclareRobustCommand\foo{foo}` and such macro will be not expanded by `\xdef`.