# Make only first space active

Tags: macros, expl3, latex3, active-characters

This is follow up to a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/684330/213149) that has been closed because it was treated wrongly.

Brief recap: let `\newcommand{\foo}{foo}`. Having `\foo` in text like so

```
test \foo bar
```

will omit the space after `\foo` which will result in `test foobar`, while

```
test {\foo} bar
test {\foo}.
```

produces `test foo bar` and `test foo.` which is exactly what I need.

---

While it's not possible to brace a macro before it's being parsed, there is a way to make   space an active character.

Here's the [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235188/213149) by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) that's close to what I'm looking for. However it uses an additional environment wrapper.

My question is how to apply the same technique of creating space active but only once, right after `\foo`? So that `\foo` takes one argument, parses it with respect to the spaces and puts `#1 foo` in the text maintaining the space if one was present.

Comment: any answer to your previous question woud be an answer to the general question about space after commands so closing as dup seemed OK to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution I can think of which uses just plain TeX.

```tex
\def\checkspace{\catcode`\ =12\relax\futurelet\csps\checkspaceA}
\def\checkspaceA{\catcode`\ =10\relax\if\space\csps\ \afterassignment\ignorespaces\expandafter\let\expandafter\csps\fi}

\def\foo{foo\checkspace}

test \foo   bar

test foo bar

test \foo.

\bye
```

---

The idea is like so: `\checkspace` first makes spaces *other* so that they are not skipped and can be `\futurelet`'d.
Then we inspect the next token in `\checkspaceA` using `\futurelet`.
`\checkspaceA` makes spaces space tokens again, and if the token we are inspecting is a space, then a `\`  is inserted.

The purpose of the rest of the code inside the conditional in `\checkspaceA` is to make sure that if `\checkspace` is followed by multiple spaces, all the spaces following the first are ignored.
First I will explain the issue (to my understanding) so I can better explain my solution.

If we were to remove this code from `\checkspaceA` and do the following test:

```tex
\def\checkspaceA{\catcode`\ =10\relax\if\space\csps\ \fi}

test \foo bar
```

Then we would get `test foo` followed by a space, then an *other* space character (which looks like a slanted dash in cmr), then `bar`.
The issue is that once we do `\futurelet\csps\checkspaceA` in `\checkspace`, the token following `\foo` is tokenized into an *other* space token, and left in the stream, and this is what creates the weird dash character.

So we can alter the code slightly to get rid of this:

```tex
\def\checkspaceA{\catcode`\ =10\relax\if\space\csps\ \expandafter\let\expandafter\csps\fi}

test \foo  bar
```

But now the issue is that since there are two spaces following `\foo`, the first one is correctly converted into `\`  by `\checkspaceA`.
But the next space token really followed an *other* token, and is therefore not ignored.
Doing `\afterassignment\ignorespaces` before the `\let` ensures that it is ignored.

---

This solution will not work for any character with catcode 10, and setting up the macros so that they work for other characters requires changing the catcodes of multiple characters and nesting `\if`s.

In general I don't really see a reason to for these macros, I think it may just be simpler to follow your macros with an empty group.
You almost certainly won't run into weird unintended side effects doing so.

I'm not 100% sure that my macros will always work, if there is an issue with them, feel free to tell me and I'd be happy to attempt to fix them.

Comment: Works perfectly as I expected. Thank you for such a detailed answer, I appreciate that.