# What is the best (easiest) way to indent lines of math without defining columns (think pseudocode)

Tags: math-mode, indentation

All the ways I see to align things in math mode have you set columns, but I only care about where a line of math starts. I want to be able to write something like:

```
f:A\to \mathbb{R}\\       % indent 0
if \all x_0\in A\\        % indent 0
  \all \varepsilon>0\\    % indent 2
    \exists \delta s.t.\\ % indent 4
      x\in A\\            % indent 6
      if |x-x_0|<\delta\\ % indent 6
       \to|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon\\ % indent 7
 \to f \text{continuous [cont.]}      % indent 1
```

The multiline environment allows me to do multiple lines, but I cannot indent without defining columns which is not what I want (the end of the line should go arbitrarily far). Bonus points if the indentation level defaults to that of the previous line.

Comment: Do you want this entire construction centred or aligned to the left of the text block? Should it be breakable across the page boundary?

Comment: I had originally intended to left align it, but it would be nice to center it. If a line is too long, I expected to manually break the line up and indent the trailing line, but if you have something fancy in mind to automate the splitting of lines that go off the page, do tell.

Comment: There are various algorithm packages available, although I don't know if they support your particular variety of pseudocode.  (I've always wondered what function pseudocode satisfies, since it isn't standardized and is therefore subject to interpretation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was, what is the **easiest** way to do it. Maybe more easy than to write two `$` at each line is the following solution.

```
{\catcode`\ =13 \gdef\dospace#1{\ifx#1 \hskip1em\else\catcode`\ =13\relax#1\fi}
\gdef\runindent{\bgroup\def\If{{\rm if}\ }
\def\par{\hfil\break\null\catcode`\ =13\relax}\obeylines   
\catcode`\ =13\def {\futurelet\next\dospace}\noindent$}}
\def\endindent{$\egroup}

\runindent
f \colon A \to R
\If \forall x_0 \in A
  \forall \varepsilon > 0
    \exists \delta {\rm s.t.}
    x \in A
      \If |x - x_0| < \delta
       \to |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon
 \to f \hbox{continuous [cont.]}
\endindent
```

Comment: OK, this looks perfect, but I cant really follow the first block you have. I tried to compile this with the first block before and after \begin{document}, but either way I get an error: "Style option: `fancyvrb' v3.3 <2019/10/22> (tvz)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)) (./temp.aux)
! Extra else.
is@range ...->if >#2expandafter check@single else 
                                                  expandafter check@range fi 
l.24 \runindent"

Comment: @zacchaeus I added `\bye` at the end ad I compiled this by `pdftex document` without errors.

Comment: @zacchaeus OK, my mistake. I can't re-define \if. So, \If is defined here. See my new version of the answer.

Comment: This answers the question I asked PERFECTLY (I did not specify TeX or LaTeX), but I need it to work in a LaTeX format, and my LaTeX-foo isn't good enough to adapt this to a LaTeX format (pdftex -> pdflatex).

Comment: @zacchaeus: See [this setup](https://pastebin.com/raw/GYN5KhPK) to use it in LaTeX.

Comment: That worked! thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own [`fancyvrb`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) environment, similar to what is suggested in [Environment that obeys spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53723/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,fancyvrb}

\let\all\forall% Whatever your \all implies

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment
  {MathIndent}
  {Verbatim}
  {fontfamily=cmr,
   commandchars=\\\{\},
  codes={\catcode`$=3\catcode`^=7\catcode`_=8}
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{MathIndent}
$f \colon A \to \mathbb{R}$
if $\all x_0 \in A$
  $\all \varepsilon > 0$
    $\exists \delta \text{s.t.}$
    $x \in A$
      if $\lvert x - x_0 \rvert < \delta$
       $\to \lvert f(x) - f(x_0) \rvert < \varepsilon$
 $\to f \text{continuous [cont.]}$
\end{MathIndent}

\end{document}
```

---

The `tabbing` environment allows similar alignments setting (of "tab stops") via `\=` and jumping/skipping via `\>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\newcommand{\mindent}{\hspace{2em}}
\let\all\forall

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
\= \mindent \= \mindent \= \mindent \= \kill                   \\
$f \colon A \to \mathbb{R}$                                    \\ % indent 0
if $\all x_0 \in A$                                            \\ % indent 0
\> $\all \varepsilon > 0$                                      \\ % indent 2
\> \> $\exists \delta \text{s.t.}$                             \\ % indent 4
\> \> \> $x \in A$                                             \\ % indent 6
\> \> \> if $\lvert x - x_0 \rvert < \delta$                   \\ % indent 6
\> \> \> \quad $\to \lvert f(x) - f(x_0) \rvert < \varepsilon$ \\ % indent 7
\quad $\to f \text{continuous [cont.]}$                           % indent 1
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You, my friend, are a gentleman and a scholar.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the `fleqn`  environment from `nccmath`,an `align*` environment and the optional argument of `MoveEqLeft` command from `mathtools`; the implicit unit of this command is `em`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}%
    \begin{align*}
     & f:A\to \mathbb{R}\\ % indent 0
     &\text{if }\forall x_0\in A\\ % indent 0
    \MoveEqLeft[-2] \forall \varepsilon>0\\ % indent 2
    \MoveEqLeft[-4] \exists\, \delta \text{ s. t.} \\ % indent 4
    \MoveEqLeft[-6] x \in A\\ % indent 6
    \MoveEqLeft[-6]\text{if }|x-x_0|<\delta \\ % indent 6
    \MoveEqLeft[-7] \to|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon\\ % indent 7
    [![enter image description here][1]][1]\MoveEqLeft[-1]\to f \text{ continuous [cont.]} % indent 1
    \end{align*}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]